# Python ThreadPoolExecutor and psycopg2 -- process exits before completion

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm currently building an application that uses the ThreadPoolExecutor, like so:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 6) as executor:
   for ns in newssource:
      executor.submit(myFunc, ns)
```

Within myFunc, I do three things:

1. Download a TXT file.
2. Analyze the TXT file and save it locally.
3. Reopen the TXT file and save additional info to Postgres (via psycopg2).

The process always ends before #3 is complete -- I think the connection errors out but I don't see any error messages. The process just ends... Even when I create a Postgres connection and cursor within the third function, at the very final step.

I can't seem to find documentation on this. Any advice/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As an update, I'm even more confused now.

By adding ```f = executor.submit(myFunc, ns)``` (i.e., assign the result of the executor), everything seems to be working. I'm glad it works but am trying to figure out why -- any feedback would be great!

Comment: Are you connecting to PostgreSQL in the main thread or does each process have its own connection? You cannot share a single PostgreSQL connection between multiple processes.

Comment: Thanks for asking -- I'm creating the PostgreSQL connection and cursor in the final part of the function -- so within its own thread, yes.